# When attempting to remove a document in Meteor: "Remove failed: Internal server error"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am attempting to remove a document by the ObjectId.

```
Template.conferenceItem.events({
    'click #delete' : function () {
        Conferences.remove(this._id);
    }
});
```

In my console I get "remove failed: Internal server error". I get the same error if I run this in the console: `Conferences.remove('tfD9KQsFp8LoftHgS')`, where `tfD9KQsFp8LoftHgS` is an existing ObjectId.

**Edit:**

I have the following code in my collections folder in conferences.js:

```
Conferences = new Meteor.Collection('conferences');

Conferences.allow({
  remove: function(userID, doc){
    // only allow remove if you are logged in
    return !! userId;
  }
});
```

Comment: In the `allow` you have `userID` yet you are returning based on `userId` (notice the *d* difference). Check to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have a typo in the function associated with remove. The meteor doc example

```
remove: function (userId, doc) {
    // can only remove your own documents
    return doc.owner === userId; 
}
```

so change userID to userId

Answer (score 1):

**This is probably a Meteor [*allow*](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow) error.**

> **Collection.allow**: Allow users to write directly to this collection from client code, subject to limitations you define.

You must authorize your untrusted client code to *allow* removes on the server somewhere in your code?

You probably want to do something like this, in your *server* code:

```
Conferences.allow({

  remove: function (userId, doc) {
  // check for proper permissions using passed arguments if any here
  return true;
}

});
```

Comment: I have code to allow logged-in users to insert/update/remove; see my edit above for the code. I'm able to insert/update as expected when logged in.

Comment: Are you using multiple `#Ids`?  Have you tried `this.userId`?  See http://docs.meteor.com/#publish_userId.  Which `userId` is that in your allow code?  Have you looked at that closer?